# Python - Having trouble with pandas.DataFrame.append

Tags: python, pandas, append

Can someone please help me figure out why the quer.append(l) is not working?  My query for 'quer' and 'l' seem to work correctly. quer returns 31 rows (all rows that are "YES" in the Hill column. And 'l' returns 9 rows (all rows that are "YES" in the Underwater column). I then try to append the two together, but that doesn't seem to be workings. The 'return quer' is just returning the 31 YES that are in the Hill column and is not appending the 'l' dataframe

CSV: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PjnN00bikJfY7mO3xt4nV5Ua1yOIsh8DycGqed6hWD8/edit?usp=sharing

Workflow: save the csv as Monsters.csv and python file in the same folder and run the python file

```
import pandas as pd
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

currentDir = os.getcwd()

data = pd.read_csv(r'Monsters.csv')

def biomes(biome):
        ind = 0
        for i in range(len(biome)):
            if i == 0:
                quer = data.query("{} == 'YES'".format(biome[ind]))
                print ("Hill:", quer)  # returns 31 rows
            if i > 0:
                l = data.query("{} == 'YES'".format(biome[ind]))
                quer.append(l)   #this append is not working
                print ("Underwater: ", l ) #returns 9 rows
            ind += 1
        return quer # returns 31 rows (only the Hill biome) for some reason.

print(biomes(["Hill", "Coast"]))
```

Comment: Hi Brack, can you define what you mean when you say it is "not working"? If you are getting an error thrown, can you post the error text?

Comment: Hi Oliver! My query for 'quer' and 'l' seem to work correctly. quer returns 31 rows (all rows that are "YES" in the Hill column. And 'l' returns 9 rows (all rows that are "YES" in the Underwater column). I then try to append the two together, but that doesn't seem to be workings. The 'return quer' is just returning the 31 YES that are in the Hill column and is not appending the 'l' dataframe. I hope that helps clear things up, let me know if you have any more questions! : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), `DataFrame.append()` returns a new object - it does not modify the object it is being called on. As such, I believe your `append()` is creating a new DataFrame, but not assigning it anywhere.

Try replacing `quer.append(l)` with `quer = quer.append(l)` to resolve this.

Comment: You are awesome! Not only does this answer my question, but it also helps me better understand how pandas handles objects. Thank you so much!!